# How to get from my initial url to destination html in R with rvest package

Tags: r, session, rvest, rselenium

Im trying to get to my final `html` page with [rvest](/questions/tagged/rvest) package. I know how to solve this problem with `RSelenium`, but I would like to do it with `rvest`. I've never scraped pages with such kind of problems (session/cookies) with `rvest`.

I've googled many approaches but none of them worked. I come to a form

```
library(rvest)

mysession <- html_session("http://www.sicris.si/public/jqm/search_basic.aspx?lang=eng&opdescr=search&opt=2&subopt=1&code1=cmn&code2=auto&search_term=27772")

form<-mysession %>% jump_to("http://www.sicris.si/search/rsr_biblio.aspx?lang=slv&id=20471")%>%html_form() 

form
```

My initial URL/page is http://www.sicris.si/public/jqm/search_basic.aspx?lang=eng&opdescr=search&opt=2&subopt=1&code1=cmn&code2=auto&search_term=27772.

Then you have to click on link "Evaluation of bibliographic indicators of scientific performance acording to the ARRS" and you get a new page (only in slovene). To get to the destination/final result, you should press submit button "Dalje".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.